# How can I join 2 tables and match the null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
mysql> select bookId, productId, clusterId, symbolId, shares from SymbolAimOrderStats where bookId = "BFM";
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| bookId | productId | clusterId | symbolId | shares |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| BFM    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL     |    522 |
| BFM    | BFM       | NULL      | NULL     |    522 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | NULL     |    522 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 0000f52a |    506 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a4d |      2 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a7c |      1 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a89 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010ba3 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c7e |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c97 |      4 | 
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select bookId, productId, clusterId, symbolId, shares from SymbolOrderStats where bookId = "BFM";
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| bookId | productId | clusterId | symbolId | shares |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| BFM    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL     |    393 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | NULL      | NULL     |    393 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | NULL     |    393 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 0000f52a |    377 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a4d |      2 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a7c |      1 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a89 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010ba3 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c7e |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c97 |      4 | 
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to join these tables and get the shares column from both, including the rows that have NULLs.

I know that you cannot match NULLs, so this of course does not give me my desired result:

```
mysql> select a.bookId, a.productId, a.clusterId, a.symbolId, a.shares, o.shares 
from SymbolAimOrderStats a 
left join SymbolOrderStats o 
on a.bookId = o.bookId and a.productId = o.productId and 
a.clusterId = o.clusterId and a.symbolId = o.symbolId where a.bookId = "BFM";
```

So I've tried this:

```
mysql> select a.bookId, a.productId, a.clusterId, a.symbolId, a.shares, o.shares 
from SymbolAimOrderStats a 
left join SymbolOrderStats o 
on a.bookId = o.bookId and 
(a.productId = o.productId or (a.productId is null and o.productId is null)) and 
(a.clusterId = o.clusterId or (a.clusterId is null and o.clusterId is null)) and
(a.symbolId = o.symbolId or (a.symbolId is null or a.symbolId is null)) 
where a.bookId = "BFM";
```

But that also does not give what I want. Can someone please tell me how I can get the result set I want?

Here is what I want returned:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
| bookId | productId | clusterId | symbolId | shares | shares |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
| BFM    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL     |    522 |    393 |
| BFM    | BFM       | NULL      | NULL     |    522 |    393 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | NULL     |    522 |    393 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 0000f52a |    506 |    377 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a4d |      2 |      2 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a7c |      1 |      1 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010a89 |      3 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00010ba3 |      3 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c7e |      3 |      3 | 
| BFM    | BFM       | BFM       | 00013c97 |      4 |      4 | 
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is in MySQL.

Comment: You have not shown us what you want yet. Please post the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear. I have updated my question with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the last condition on the `NULL` values should use `and` instead of `or`:

```
select a.bookId, a.productId, a.clusterId, a.symbolId, a.shares, o.shares 
from SymbolAimOrderStats a 
left join SymbolOrderStats o 
on a.bookId = o.bookId and 
(a.productId = o.productId or (a.productId is null and o.productId is null)) and 
(a.clusterId = o.clusterId or (a.clusterId is null and o.clusterId is null)) and
(a.symbolId = o.symbolId or (a.symbolId is null and o.symbolId is null)) 
------------------------------------------------^ --^
where a.bookId = "BFM";
```

Comment: also it should be o.symbolId after the and

Comment: Thank you both - 2 dumb typos.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `NULL` to be meaningful, change it to something meaningful.

```
select  a.bookId, a.productId, a.clusterId, a.symbolId, a.shares, o.shares 
from    SymbolAimOrderStats a 
left join SymbolOrderStats o 
  on    a.bookId = o.bookId
   and ifnull( a.productId, @dummy ) = ifnull( o.productId, @dummy )
   and ifnull( a.clusterId, @dummy ) = ifnull( o.clusterId, @dummy )
   and ifnull( a.symbolId, @dummy ) = ifnull( o.symbolId, @dummy ) 
where a.bookId = "BFM";
```

Where `@dummy` is anything as long as it doesn't conflict with non-null values to eliminate the possibility of matching a `NULL` with a non-`NULL` and is the same data type as the field. If productId, clusterId and symbolId are different types, you'll need three dummy variables. Or you can hardcode values there, but that's not a good practice.

However, this raises the question that if the `NULL` values in your tables actually mean something, why aren't they already set to those values? I don't mean to be critical -- there could be perfectly reasonable reasons they have to remain `NULL`. But maybe you could be overlooking an opportunity to improve your data.

Comment: The data is created by a query selecting with rollup. The NULL values are aggregates over all the symbols, or clusters and symbols, or products, clusters, and symbols. Yeah, the code that creates the data could change the nulls to something else, but there's a lot of existing code out there that expects the NULLs to indicate the aggregates.